# Help with Second order linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Please help with the following problem:

> Let $ϕ$ be a solution of the equation $y''+a_1y'+a_2y=0$, where $a_1,a_2$ are constants. If $ψ(x) = e^{(\frac{a_1}{2})x}ϕ(x)$, show that $ψ$ satisfies an equation $y''+ky=0$, where $k$ is some constant. Compute $k$.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your own thoughts on the problem?

Comment: what have you done already?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$ψ(x) = e^{\frac{a_1}{2}x}ϕ(x)$$
$$ψ'(x) = \frac{a_1}{2}e^{\frac{a_1}{2}x}ϕ(x)+e^{\frac{a_1}{2}x}ϕ'(x)$$
and take second derivate $ψ''(x)$ then substitute in $\dfrac{y''}{y}$.

Comment: Substitute in to $y′′+ky=0$?

Comment: You can substitute in $y''+ky$ and show it is zero for a $k$, but my offer is better, because you don't know what's $k$.